# How to launch rtabmap_ros?

Tags: ros2, kinect, imu, rtabmap, rtabmap-ros

I have been following the Nav2 tutorial when I reached the robot_localization part and decided to launch rtabmap using a Kinect rgbd camera for map generation

I found this schema which I need to implement, so far I only publish on the imu topic
I'm not sure where to start to start publishing odom accordingly:

```
RGBD data ---> rgbd_node of rtabmap ---> visual odometry (/vo)

IMU raw data ---> Madgwick filter ---> orientation estimation in ENU frame (/imu/data)

(/vo) + (/imu/data) ---> ekf_node ---> filtered_odometry (/odometry/filtered)

(/odometry/filtered) ---> rtabmap ---> map_data
```

1)Do I need to launch rtabmap node first to be able to publish rgbd data on this topic /rtabmap/**rgbd_image** ? Do I edit my original launch file which already launches rviz and gazebo or do I need to create multiple launch files in my project?

2)Do I need to integrate the Kinect camera to my urdf file first as a normal sensor?

Coming to the robot_localization part,
I found a sensor_fusion.launch file on the original rtabmap_ros repository which I'm not sure where to place in my file system https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap_ros/blob/master/rtabmap_examples/launch/sensor_fusion.launch

3)or would configuring a ekf.yaml using robot localization to perform sensor fusion between /vo and /imu/data substitute that?

4)which parts of the rtabmap_ros repository will I find myself in need for?